# Django m2m запись

Tags: django, sqlite

Всем доброго времени суток. Пишу web-system'у и возникла проблема с записью m2m значений. Вот моя models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    species = models.ForeignKey('Species_project', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    species_task = models.ForeignKey('Species_Task', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    created_task = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата создания',auto_now_add=True)
    finish_task = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата окончания')
    user = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User')
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

вот views:

```
def create_project_task(request, pk):
task_species = Species_Task.objects.all()
user_list = User.objects.all()

if request.method == 'POST':
    name = request.POST.get('name')
    description = request.POST.get('description')
    species_task = request.POST.get('species_task')
    date_finish = request.POST.get('finish_date')
    user_task = request.POST.get('user_task')
    Project.objects.get_or_create(name = name, species_id=pk, species_task_id=species_task, user=user_task, finish_task=date_finish, description=description)


return render(request, 'projects/create_project_task.html', {'task_species': task_species, 'user_list':user_list})
```

и сама html от куда я беру значения на запись:

```
<select name="user_task" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2" multiple="multiple">{% for itm in user_list %}>
    <option value={{ itm.id }}>
        {{ itm.first_name }}&nbsp{{ itm.last_name }}
    </option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

У меня не получается через html передовать во views и записывать его в бд. Через админ панель все работает, исполнители прикрепляются к задачам, а вот как сделать это через html и реализовать во view. так же вылетает вот такая ошибка

Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use user.set() instead.

Если кто знает или сталкивался с подобной проблемой,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем решил свою проблему сам. Я создал вручную доп. таблицу в модели которая выглядит вот так:

```
class UserProject(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

Она принимает в себя id проекта и id пользователя

а потом во views я делаю вот так:

```
    user_task = request.POST.getlist('user_task')
    project_task = Project.objects.get_or_create(name = name, species_id=pk,  species_task_id=species_task, finish_task=date_finish, description=description)

for itm in user_task:
        UserProject.objects.get_or_create(project = project_task[0], user_id = int(itm))
```

записываю в list id всех пользователей, в project_task, после записи в бд, так же хранится id проекта, у них в кортеже 0 номер эллемента, а потом с помощью цикла for записываем в нашу доп. таблицу. Вот и все, оказалось все горазда легче, нужно было всего лишь прочитать документацию

Answer (score 0):

```
project = Project.objects.get_or_create(name = name, species_id=pk,
                                        species_task_id=species_task,
                                        finish_task=date_finish, description=description)
user = User.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('user_task'))
project.user.add(user);
```

Comment: Не получается выводит ошибку 
'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'add'

Comment: Надо обращаться к полям объекта, а не класса.

Comment: А можно по подробнее, только начинаю изучать django, немного не понятно. Я уже создал новую модель "ExtUser".
Как я понял, надо я обращаюсь к project, в котором хрянится выборка по запросу, но когда я добавляю через него, он выводит ошибку "'tuple' object has no attribute 'user'"

Comment: Судя по ошибке, вы обращаетесь к кортежу. Вам стоит сначала взять учебник и изучить Python, а уж потом браться за Django.